# How to add decimal parts in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query in SQL Server 2008 which produce resulting fiels price as `23456,34567,3455.66` etc. But I want to display it as `23456.00,34567.00,3455.66`.

How can I do it?

My query is

```
(isnull(sum(TE.Quantity),0) *  isnull(MAX(TE.FullPrice),0) ) As Price,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you do an explicit cast:

```
 select cast(coalesce(sum(TE.Quantity) * MAX(TE.FullPrice),0) as decimal(18, 2)) as Price
```

Or, if you prefer `isnull`:

```
select cast(isnull(sum(TE.Quantity) * MAX(TE.FullPrice),0) as decimal(18, 2)) as Price
```

You can do the NULL comparison after the multiplication, because you want `0` in the end anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to a `decimal` with two digits precision:

```
cast(...your calculation here... as decimal(10,2))
```